# How to understand Neo4j spatial nodes after importing from OSM file

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I have imported an OSM file to Neo4j, When I try to find nodes near by one location, I used
 
`CALL spatial.closest("sg_osm",POINT({longitude:103.9451838,latitude:1.352351217}),0.0001)`

Below is the response node, how do I understand this node as there is no lat/lon as the property, what does this node mean ? and gtype 2? If I want to search this node, what will be my cypher query?

```
{
  "vertices": 25,
  "gtype": 2,
  "bbox": [
    103.9441967,
    103.9452897,
    1.3520486,
    1.3530789
  ]
}
```

Comment: We need more information. I presume OSM is Open Street Map data. Can you state the problem more clearly. Are you trying to determine proximity of a property/house/business/customer to something else (what else?). Can you show us the schema or sample of the neo4j starting data you are querying.

Comment: I downloaded osm file from https://extract.bbbike.org/, format OSM XML 7z. Then followed https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial "Importing an Open Street Map file". The nodes generated is like above. I'm trying to find a node that is close to my location, then save the node for my future reference. But given the node above, what property should I save, so that I can locate the node easily in the future?